# FormWizard and saving data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

im trying to use django formWizard, all is fine, but im getting an error in the last step after submit

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/vacantes/webapps/django/lib/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/home/vacantes/webapps/django/lib/python2.6/django/utils/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapper
   return decorator(bound_func)(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/home/vacantes/webapps/django/lib/python2.6/django/utils/decorators.py", line 76, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/home/vacantes/webapps/django/lib/python2.6/django/utils/decorators.py", line 17, in bound_func
   return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)

 File "/home/vacantes/webapps/django/lib/python2.6/django/contrib/formtools/wizard.py", line 101, in __call__
   return self.done(request, final_form_list)

 File "/home/vacantes/webapps/django/hay_vacantes/curriculums/forms.py", line 56, in done
   website = data['website']

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'website'
```

i dont know where is the problem, in my Model i have a website field, but ... why the error?

## model.py

```
class Generales(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True)
    .....
    estado_civil = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=1,choices=CIVIL)
    website      = models.URLField(verbose_name='Website', verify_exists=False,null=True,blank=True)
```

and in my forms:

## forms.py

```
#others forms
.....

class ContactWizard(FormWizard):
    def done(self, request, form_list):
        data = {}
        for form in form_list:
            data.update(form.cleaned_data)

        generales = Generales(
            usuario             = request.user.id,
            documento_identidad = data['documento_identidad'],
            tipo                = data['tipo'],
            tel_fijo            = data['tel_fijo'],
            celular             = data['celular'],
            foto                = data['foto'],
            sexo                = data['sexo'],
            direccion           = data['direccion'],
            codigo_postal       = data['codigo_postal'],
            pais                = data['pais'],
            ciudad              = data['ciudad'],
            fecha_nacimiento    = data['fecha_nacimiento'],
            estado_civil        = data['estado_civil'],
            website             = data['website']
        )
        generales.save()


        # others forms
        .....
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/panel/completo/')
```

## EDIT

urls.py

```
from vacantes.curriculums.forms import Generales,Areas,Experiencia,Referencias,ContactWizard


urlpatterns = patterns('',
              url(r'^completar/$', ContactWizard([Generales, Areas,Experiencia,Referencias])),
)
```

i dont know if im saving the data like formwizard need, but im trying.

any idea about the error?

thanks

Comment: How are you instantiating the form instance?

Comment: Can you publish a bit more of the stacktrace? Which Object's __init__ is called? Why don't you use ModelForms and call save on them directly?

Answer (score 0):

As i have already used FormWizard in my app, the keys of submitted data are not 'website' or 'estado_civil',...  but in the form "< form_number>-< field_name>". For example: '0-website' if the field 'website' is in the first form, '1-website' if it is in the second form and so on.
You can print out the whole submitted data dictionary to check that.